# Shiny and Firefox enter key event

Tags: javascript, shiny

i have a Shiny app that i run in Firefox browser.
In the App there is a input Matrix where i change Values. The main problem is, that if i change e.g: a value in the fist "cell" from 80 to 100 and then pressing enter key, the 80 remains.But if i change the 80 to 100 and click on the "cell" below the 100 appears and is now in the values of the matrix.

The firefox Inspector on the "cell" gives following keydown-event:

```
function(e) {
  if (
    // no bubbling, should always fire.
    // this is just a safety net in case event.timeStamp is unreliable in
    // certain weird environments...
    e.target === e.currentTarget ||
    // event is fired after handler attachment
    e.timeStamp >= attachedTimestamp ||
    // bail for environments that have buggy event.timeStamp implementations
    // #9462 iOS 9 bug: event.timeStamp is 0 after history.pushState
    // #9681 QtWebEngine event.timeStamp is negative value
    e.timeStamp <= 0 ||
    // #9448 bail if event is fired in another document in a multi-page
    // electron/nw.js app, since event.timeStamp will be using a different
    // starting reference
    e.target.ownerDocument !== document
  ) {
    return original.apply(this, arguments)
  }
}
```

.... i'm not familar to JS :( am i right that it returns the old, original (80) value instead of the new 100? How can i fix it?

Please help me :)

Comment: No, as an event handler, it doesn't return anything you could access later in your code.

Comment: But why it changes on klick by mouse on the next matrix value and not by enter?

Comment: Please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).